# porting kernel config to different architecture

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

I have a good Kernel `.config` setup for x86 that I'm happy with.

Now I have a few different ARM-based devices (some without video output) that all come with their default pre-configured settings.

I'd like to bring the configuration of all targets as close as possible - for example, so that all have the same file systems enabled etc.

Simply copying the `.config` around won't work as hardware-specific, important settings (that come with the default config) will get lost.

Basically low-level settings (processor details, I/O mappings, ...) should be left as-is and high-level settings (enabled file systems, USB device drivers, security options and lots and lots of settings that don't come to my mind right now) should be shared by all configs.

Is there some sort of "best practice" for such situations or do I really have to check 3000+ settings manually?

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel configuration includes a lot of hardware specific detail, like enabling drivers for devices. It is very unlikely that that can be moved over from one architecture to the other (except for closely related ones, like x86 and x86_64). Besides, ARM chips are configured from a menu of on-chip devices, which require special configuration handling. This makes ARM even more different in configuration handling from your PC than, say, a x86_64 and a SPARC64 are.

You will have to tweak the configuration for your specific use once. You should use one of the menu driven configuration tools, which will allow you to keep configuration areas as they are without much work.

Comment: I am aware that the /hardware/ is mostly incompatible and needs special handling. However, it would be a big help to somehow import hardware-unrelated settings, like enabled file systems or USB drivers, for example. I don't know, something like copying a whole submenu. Right now I am in a tedious cycle of configure, build, test, find out what's missing, reconfigure...

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but hopefully my answer may help someone else.

1. Copy the kernel source to the ARM SoC with the x86 `.config` inside
2. run `make olddefconfig`, which will create a new `.config` by taking the values of your x86 `.config` and the default one for ARM
3. now build the kernel, you won't be asked for anything since it is all covered by some of the default settings for ARM and some from your x86 settings